# Why does my code not assign the value to the variable

Tags: angular, httpclient

I have a method that gets data from an API that I am trying to assign to a variable `PartData`.

```
export interface PartInfo{
    PartData: Parts[];
}

getSpecificPart() {
  this.partService.getSpecificPart().subscribe((response: PartInfo) => {
    // Debugger
    console.log(response);
    this.partInfo.PartData = response?.PartData?.map((item) => {
      return {
        PartNum: item?.PartNum,
        PartDescrition: item?.PartDescrition,
        PartName: item?.PartName,
        // Add other required properties for Parts here
      } as Parts;
    });
  });
}
```

The value I get for `console.log(response);` is the correct response.

But when I run `console.log(this.partInfo.PartData);` the result in the browser is `Undefined`:
[image: Undefined]

I am expecting this to have the value of response which is:
[image: Correct Result]

Comment: try this console.log(response?.PartData); see what it gives you

Comment: look at your correct response carefully, these are in camel case with lowercase first letter, e.g `item?.partDescription`, also check spelling. Be careful when asserting types of response objects

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick` event calls the `getSpecificPart()` method which subscribes to an observable.  The value of `this.partInfo.PartData` is not set until the observable emits a value.

The problem is that in your code:

```js
1    onClick() {
2        this.getSpecificPart();
3        console.log(this.partInfo.PartData);
4    }
```

line 2 is executed, which internally subscribes to the observable, then line 3 is executed before the value has been set, so the value is still `undefined`.  Then the subscribe callback is executed, which sets the value.

---

I'm not sure of your intent, but one solution could be to have your method return and observable and subscribe to that inside your click handler.

```js
getSpecificPart(): Observable<Parts> {
    return this.partService.getSpecificPart().pipe(
        map(response => response?.PartData?.map(item => ({
            PartNum: item?.PartNum,
            PartDescrition: item?.PartDescrition,
            PartName: item?.PartName,
        })))
    );
}
```

```js
onClick() {
    this.getSpecificPart().subscribe(
        partInfo => console.log(partInfo.PartData)
    );
}
```